# dplyr::group_modify to apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to apply a function (calculate the binomial confidence interval) on each group in a dataframe. Assume that I have a dataframe containing the following:

```
 df <- data.frame(group_name = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = T), numbers = 1:20, other_numbers = 51:70)
```

I group by the group_name and create a vector to feed into the exactci function:

```
install.packages('PropCIs');library('PropCIs') 

df2 <- df %>% 
   group_by(group_name) %>% 
   vector = c(numbers, other_numbers) %>%
   mutate(CI = exactci(vector, conf.level = 0.95))
```

But the levels of my binomial variable are unavailable.

Ideally, I would also like to apply dplyr::group_modify to create a table that contains the confidence intervals for the binomial variable for each group, in addition to the new variable in the dataframe that contains the CIs.

Comment: Maybe the package `broom` will be helpful in this case: it converts the output of a model or stat test into a small data frame. However I am not sure it integrates well with PropCIs. See https://broom.tidyverse.org/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make this clean as possible. I bet someone can make a cleaner looking code. Cheers.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group_name = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = T), numbers = 1:20, other_numbers = 51:70)

mean_ci <- function(x, conf = 0.95) {
  se <- sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))
  alpha <- 1 - conf
  mean(x) + se * qnorm(c(alpha / 2, 1 - alpha / 2))
}

df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(group_name) %>%
  mutate(n_LCI = mean_ci(numbers)[1],
         n_UCI = mean_ci(numbers)[2],
         on_LCI = mean_ci(other_numbers)[1],
         on_UCI = mean_ci(other_numbers)[2])
```

Comment: But I would like to use the function specified, I don't want to calculate the mean CI for both variables. I want the confidence interval of two levels of the binomial variable (numbers and other numbers).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I am using `exactci()` properly but perhaps `nest()` can be of some assistance.

```r
df <- data.frame(
  group_name = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = T), 
  numbers = 1:20, 
  other_numbers = 51:70
)

library(PropCIs)
library(tidyverse) # tidyverse loads both dplyr and tidyr

df %>%
  nest(CI = -group_name) %>%
  mutate(CI = map(CI, ~ exactci(x = .x$numbers,
                                n = .x$other_numbers,
                                conf.level = .95) %>%
    unlist())
  ) %>%
  unnest_wider(CI)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 15
#>   group_name conf.int1 conf.int2 conf.int3 conf.int4 conf.int5 conf.int6
#>   <fct>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 c           0.000496    0.115     0.155     0.184      0.104     0.327
#> 2 b           0.00469     0.0722    0.132     0.270     NA        NA    
#> 3 a           0.0118      0.0508    0.125     0.157      0.237     0.340
#> 4 e           0.0206      0.0403    0.104     0.135      0.145     0.165
#> 5 d           0.0302      0.0615    0.0829    0.0936     0.200     0.254
#> # ... with 8 more variables: conf.int7 <dbl>, conf.int8 <dbl>,
#> #   conf.int9 <dbl>, conf.int10 <dbl>, conf.int11 <dbl>, conf.int12 <dbl>,
#> #   conf.int13 <dbl>, conf.int14 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

`nest()` acts like a sort of `group_by()` and `map()` makes for easy application of functions like `exactci()`.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This worked for you on the sample dataset provided? I get an error that CI cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure from your question whether (or how) you would like to compute a **single** CI for each group. But you could run `exactci` in a rowwise fashion, as follows:

```
library('PropCIs') 
df <- data.frame(group_name = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = T), 
                 numbers = 1:20, 
                 other_numbers = 51:70)  

df2 <- df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(myci = list(exactci(numbers, other_numbers, .95) %>% unlist )) %>% 
    unnest_wider(myci)
  
# A tibble: 20 x 5
   group_name numbers other_numbers conf.int1 conf.int2
   <chr>        <int>         <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 d                1            51  0.000496     0.104
 2 a                2            52  0.00469      0.132
 3 d                3            53  0.0118       0.157
 4 c                4            54  0.0206       0.179
 5 c                5            55  0.0302       0.200
 6 c                6            56  0.0403       0.219
 7 c                7            57  0.0508       0.237
 8 e                8            58  0.0615       0.254
 9 d                9            59  0.0722       0.270
10 c               10            60  0.0829       0.285
11 e               11            61  0.0936       0.300
12 b               12            62  0.104        0.314
13 e               13            63  0.115        0.327
14 b               14            64  0.125        0.340
15 a               15            65  0.135        0.352
16 a               16            66  0.145        0.364
17 c               17            67  0.155        0.375
18 e               18            68  0.165        0.386
19 c               19            69  0.175        0.396
20 c               20            70  0.184        0.406
```